# Numbers rounding instead when not supposed to in Python

Tags: python

The issue that I'm having with this problem is that my output last 2 numbers in my output (the ones I bolded at the bottom of the post) is rounding to 7 instead of staying 68 and I'm not sure how to fix it. The program runs twice and with an Input of 10 it works but with an output of 5.5 it doesn't.

**Here's the question:**

The formula for the volume of a sphere is (4/ 3) × pi × r ^ 3. (Note that r ^ 3 means "r raised to the power of 3". Since you do not know how to raise a number to a power, you can do this by multiplying, i.e., (r x r x r).) Write a program that prompts for the radius and calculates the volume of a sphere and displays the result. Use 3.1415 as the value of PI. For example:

Enter the radius: 10.0
The volume is  4188.666666666667

My Code:

```
pi = float(3.1415)

radius = float(input('Enter the radius: '))
print(radius)

volume = (4* (radius*radius*radius)*3.1415)/3


print('The volume is ' , round(volume, 12))
```

Heres the correct output though:

Compare output:

Input: 10

Your output:
Enter the radius: 10.0
The volume is  4188.666666666667

Compare output:

Input: 5.5

Your output:
Enter the radius: 5.5
The volume is  696.88941666666**7**

Expected output:
Enter the radius: 5.5
The volume is  696.88941666666**68**

Comment: Don't see anything wrong, numbers are rounded at 12 digits, You have 13 digits in expected result.

Comment: What's your python version? I ran from Python 2.7 prompt and it worked fine

Comment: @JeremyFisher that's not the issue. The OP either doesn't understand what the `round` function does or miscounted the digits in the output.

Comment: @PaulH the expected output has 13 digits

Comment: I'm  not sure the version of Python that it is, I've been working in Zybooks because that's where my class assignments are.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post. If you have an issue with its presence, raise a moderator flag, but please don't just remove all its content.

Answer (score 0):

the result is as expected. The solution would only actually be different if round(volume, 13) is used. Only then, will 67 and 68 be seen in the two different outputs